# Synchronize ListView scroll position

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I am trying to synchronize `ListViews` scroll positions in a `ViewPager`.

I have a `ViewPager` with `Fragments` as children. Each fragment contains a `ListView`. I created a `ListViewScrollListener` interface, with which I listen to each `ListView` scroll activity. When one `ListView` is scrolled by the user, the active fragments in the `ViewPager` listen to the scroll event and call the following method on their `ListView`:

```
 listView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem, pixelOffset);
```

Sadly, the scroll positions of the `ListView` elements in the `Fragments` do not update. When I put the same `setSelectionFromTop` method in the `onResume()` method, it works like a charm, hence the position is set correctly when I swype the `ViewPager` and the `Fragments` are being created.

I also checked out StackOverflow for similar problems and tried the following solution, without positive results:

```
 mListView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem, pixelOffset);
            }
 });
```

I checked if the `setSelectionFromTop` is called correctly, and apparently it is. Any ideas why it's not working?

### Update 1

As hinted by Ne0, I also checked to run the setSelectionFromTop method inside the Fragment on the main ui thread, without any positive results.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                listView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem, pixelOffset);
            }
        });
```

Any other ideas what this could be?

Comment: Does `setSelectionFromTop` have to be called from a UI thread? It may explain why it works in `onResume`. Just a thought.

Comment: Good thought @Ne0. Sadly no positive result. I tried it and updated the original question.